# btRaycastVehicle's btWheelInfo rotation is incorrect

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I use C++ Bullet Physics. I spawn btRaycastVehicle on the btTriangleMesh. I update the wheel model by using
**vehicle->getWheelTransformWS(i).getOpenGLMatrix(mat);** matrix. As you can see in the clip below wheels steering turns OK, their positions in World Space are correct but rotations are completely off. **btWheelInfo**'s **m_rotation** or **m_deltaRotation** also give me wrong results for example after complete stop there is still some m_rotation.
Also **vehicle->getCurrentSpeedKmHour()** behaves wrong for me. When I accelerate it gives me negative number but when the throttle is released speed is again positive number. Where should I seek problem? Should I set some parameters for ground ?

Video with problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHt8TFLrrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue and now it works, take a look here: https://youtu.be/s4ElFeGeAfM
The problem was that I was not setting vehicle coordinate system. Now when I do with **vehicle->setCoordinateSystem(0,1,2);** it works perfectly.